# Inequality involving normalized complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> For some fixed integer $n$, let $N = 2^{{n}}$. Let $S \subseteq
>  [N^{2}]$ be a set such that $|S| = N$. Let
>
> $$A = \frac{1}{2^{n}}~~ \Big| \sum_{i \in S} \beta_{i} \Big|^{2}$$
>
> and
>
> $$B = \sum_{i \in Z_{even} \cap S} | \beta_{i} |^{2}.$$
>
> where each $\beta_{i}$ is a complex number, $[n] = \{1, 2, \ldots,
>  n \}$ and
>
> $$\sum_{i \in [N^{2}]} | \beta_{i} |^{2} = 1.$$
>
> $Z_{even}$ is the set of all even integers. We know that $|Z_{even} \cap S| = \frac{1}{3} |S|$. I am trying to prove that
>
> $$1 \geq \frac{\sqrt{3A} +(\sqrt{2} - 1)B}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

I have a hunch that I need to use triangle and Cauchy Schwarz inequalities but I cannot put a finger on how. Here is my incomplete attempt at a solution:

$$A \leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}~ \Bigg(\sum_{i \in S} |\beta_{i}|\Bigg)^{2} \leq  ~ \sum_{i \in S} |\beta_{i}|^{2} = B  + \sum_{i \in Z_{odd} \cap S} | \beta_{i} |^{2}.$$

I am stuck after this.

Comment: I feel like I must be confused. When $n=1$ and $\beta_1$ is a very large real number, the inequality is completely wrong. Are there some missing assumptions?

Comment: Oops, really sorry. Edited.